# Removing dynamically created page elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

Check out the behavior in the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/2rnSk/).

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('.tile').draggable();
            $('.tile').on('dragstart', function () {
                var numClones = $('.tile').length - 1
                if (numClones > 0) {
                    //why can't I use fadeOut or empty here?
                    //make sure we don't remove the clone before it's made
                    $('.tile')[numClones].remove();
                }
                console.log(numClones);
                var clone = $(this).clone();
                clone.appendTo('body');
            });
        });
```

This allows a user to create a clone of a page element on the drag event.  It also removes the previous clone.  In the commented line above, why do I get an error when I try to use `fadeOut` to remove the div from the page?  It's a jQuery object, right?  I get the error `Object #<HTMLDivElement has no method fadeOut`

Comment: No; `$('.tile')[numClones]` is the DOM node itself, not a jQuery object.

Comment: Is the original `.tile` supposed to get removed as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The index accessor of a jQuery element (which is shorthand for [`get(index)`](http://api.jquery.com/get/)) returns the DOM element. You're looking for the jQuery element, in which case you should use [`.eq(index)`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) (there is no shorthand for this one).

The only reason `remove()` works is because [it is also a DOM element method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element).

```
$('.tile').eq(numClones).fadeOut(function () {
    // make sure the old clones get deleted, not just hidden
    $(this).remove();   
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2rnSk/1/

Comment: I had this same answer and mine got downvoted. What is going on?

Comment: @Mathletics not sure, wasn't me.

Comment: @Mathletics i would wager your answer was lacking an explanation to go along with the code, though i did not downvote it.

Comment: @jbabey it didn't, but what can you do? No worries.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$($('.tile')[numClones]).fadeOut();
```

A jQuery object masquerades as an array of elements its selector matches. When you apply the index, you're returning, in your case, a `HTMLDivElement`. But if you wrap that up in a jQuery object, you should be able to apply `fadeOut` without issue.

Comment: There are plenty of ways to select the item you want without having to double-wrap jQuery.

Comment: True enough, but the OP wanted to know exactly why he was getting an error. While there are more optimum solutions, I felt that this particular explanation better explained why his code was failing.